# Print only the multiple first characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, command-line, cut

I have a big text file I want to print only the first 4 and the first 5 and the first 8 characters of each line in one command line.

For example
I have the lines:

```
123456789ab
ABCdefgih55
```

So the output have to be:

```
1234
ABCd
12345
ABCde
12345678
ABCdefgh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for len in 4 5 8; do
    cut -c "1-$len" file
done
```

This uses `cut -c` repeatedly to cut out the first part of each line of the file called `file`.  The length of the cut out bit is depending on the loop variable `len`.

If you're strict about that "one line" criteria:

```
for len in 4 5 8; do cut -c "1-$len" file; done
```

Or, as an easy to use shell function:

```
cut_to_lengths () {
    file=$1; shift
    for len do
        cut -c "1-$len" "$file"
    done
}
```

Using it:

```
$ cut_to_lengths file 4 5 8 1
1234
ABCd
12345
ABCde
12345678
ABCdefgi
1
A
```

---

In [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498986/print-only-the-multiple-first-characters/498993?noredirect=1#comment918735_498993) you specify that you don't want to output lines if they are *shorter* the cut length.

To do this, we can change the `cut` command into an `awk` command:

```
awk -v len="$len" 'length >= len { print substr($0, 1, len) }'
```

Replace the `cut -c "1-$len"` with the above `awk` command in the code above.

Comment: if i have lines contain less than 4 characters so i don't want them to be appeared in the output. If i have in the input a line contains one character for example: 1 so it will be eapeated in the out put how to prevent the lines that contain less than 4 characters from being appeared?

Comment: @Ahmed See update.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not well formated. I guess the whitespace should be a new line? If so the simplest way is to use `cut`

`$ cut -c -4 input` will print the first 4 character of each line. Repeat it with any number of characters you like.

Comment: Dear finswimmer i forgot to mention that i tried this command cut -c -4 input  but i want to do this in one command line for the all the first 4 and 5 and 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
for line in `cat input`; do echo ${line} | cut -c 1-4 && echo ${line} | cut -c 1-5 && echo ${line} | cut -c 1-8; done
```

this gives

```
1234
12345
12345678
ABCd
ABCde
ABCdefgi
```

Comment: The output does not seem to match the expected output.  Also, if any line contains filename globbing characters or spaces, your code wouldn't handle it properly.

Comment: More info [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @Zaid Amireh if i have lines contain less than 4 characters so i don't want them to be appeared in the output. If i have in the input a line contains one character for example: 1 so it will be eapeated in the out put how to prevent the lines that contain less than 4 characters from being appeared?